# Segue from UINavigation Controller to another UINavigation controller

Tags: iphone, uitableview, swift, uiviewcontroller, ios8

I am programming iOS in **Swift**.  The storyboard has 5 tab bars in the tab bar controller.  I want to transition from a ViewController in the 3rd tab bar navigation controller to a TableViewController in the 1st tab bar navigation controller. Having problems with this code in an IBAction function.

```
let destination: UITableViewController = RecallTableViewController()
navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
```

Please help! I appreciate your time!

Comment: Use selectedIndex property on the UITabController like this,
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use segues in this case. Because segues ara always create new instances of their destination view controllers. In order to change tabbar's visible tab you can set `selectedIndex` property of `UITabbarController` to desired index.